# Strange nulls appended to SOAP response

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis

I have to consume a remote SOAP web service, and some of it's fields are strings which in many cases include accents (á é í ó ú) because it's text in spanish.

What's happening is that when these strings have a letter with accents, "null" is appended to the beginning of string. I get as many nulls as accentuated letters the string has. For example:

```
<tag_x>nullme gusta esa canción</tag_x> (1 accent - 1 null)

<tag_y>nullnullnullmás información sobre la posición</tag_y> (3 accents - 3 nulls)

<tag_z>sin acentos</tag_z> (no accents - no nulls)
```

What puzzles me most is the fact that I am consuming the SOAP web service from two different computers and I get the nulls in one case and not in the other.

I build the request, send it and when I get the response I immediately print it. In one enviroment I get the nulls, in one I don't. In both cases we're using Java 1.6, axis2 to generate the stubs... I have absolutely no clue on what could be causing this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use a network monitor to see if both responses are the same before they reach the clients soap stack.

If you use Eclipse, you can use it's built-in [TCP/IP monitor](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-monitor-http-communication-in-eclipse.html) to view the raw data stream on the network connection.

If the responses are different on that low level, blaim the web service provider, showing your evidence.
If not, shame on you. ;-)

Comment: We have used SOAP UI and the response doesn't have the nulls. That's why we think it's our problem, not the provider

Comment: So you mean 'consuming the SOAP web service **on** two different computers" and not 'consuming the SOAP web service **from** two different computers'?

Comment: I'm sorry. I have some issues with prepositions. I sit on computer A, my webapp consumes the service: everything OK. I upload my webapp's war to client's QA server, it consumes the service: nulls

Comment: I have my issues with this language, too. Sorry, but I think I can't help you here without much more insight into the very details of the infrastructure setups. Roughly looks like a character set conversion problem, though I never seen it in that way (`null`s at the beginning). The null values point to a null Object that is printed, as it is in the XML, I would point to the web service provider. Maybe he is printing it, because the request from your client differs on both systems. Check your character set conversions, maybe. Then create a new question with more details on the infrastructure.